# list of previous month

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I add date format `(DD-MM-YYYY)` in this query? I've added date format after sysdate but it shows missing right parenthesis error.

```
select EXTRACT(MONTH FROM (SYSDATE,'DD-MM-YYYY'))-level mn1 
from dual
connect by level<4;
```

This should produce output like the following:

`01-NOV-15 01-OCT-15 01-SEP-15`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Can you share a sample of the output you're trying to get?

Comment: wanna get the following output. List of the previous 4 months 1st date. 01-NOV-15                                                                                                    01-OCT-15                                                                                                   01-SEP-15   etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `ADD_MONTHS()` and then `TRUNC()` to first date. Finally, convert to the format to ant using `TO_CHAR()`

```
select TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-level),'MONTH'),'DD-MM-YYYY') mn1 
from dual
connect by level<4;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in this format.

```
select EXTRACT(MONTH FROM (SYSDATE,'DD-MM-YYYY')-level) mn1 
from dual
connect by level<4;
```

Comment: I've changed bracket according to your quay but same error